# Make our own mobile web analytics

Tags: android, mobile, ios5, web-analytics

How does the mobile analytic works? What all information does this provide to the developer? Can I make my own Mobile Analytic for iOS and Android? If so what all information or things do I need to have to make it? I have seen so many tool that provide mobile analytic but how can I make my own analytic?

Comment: Why dont you use already established tools like Flurry or localytics?

Comment: There is a client requirement to prepare your own mobile analytic.

Comment: So ,I wanted to know how does this analytic works.So that I can move foreword once I have all the "working"information on analytic.

Comment: Dude, what a mission. You'll have to set up a server and get the phone communicating with it.

Comment: I have all those things working as I work for a company and they have their own servers.What else do I need Please help me if you can?Thanks

Comment: Well, you simply send messages to the server and store them there. Then you'll need to write some program (depending on how you would like the logs to be displayed) that can display all the data send from the phone. What exactly are you struggling with or are unclear about at the moment?

Comment: You would essentially, need to set up a server as already mentioned. Then you need to setup a database which will hold all your required information. Next you need to track and store all the information that you want within the code, using things such as variables, ArrayLists etc. Once you have done this you will need to connect to your database and push all this information into the relevent fields. Finally, you would need to setup a front end page which shows all you data. Very long, but that would be a way to go about it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can select **Cobub Razor** which an open source mobile analytics system and support for Android，IOS，Windows Phone. For details, you can go their official website [Cobub Developer Center](http://dev.cobub.com)